# How can I submit iOS apps to the App Store with MacBook A1181?

Tags: ios, macos, xcode9, macos-sierra, osx-elcapitan

Apple Store no longer accepts apps builded with Xcode less than 9.

I know that Xcode 9 requires at least Mac OS X 10.12 (Sierra) but this answer gave me hope:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48692923/5321513

I've a MacBook A1181 (early 2009) and I've already tried to intercept and edit all the files I think are involved in checking the version with this terminal command:

```
grep "10.12" -R --include="Info.plist" /Applications/Xcode9.2.app 2>/dev/null
```

changing the parameter "Minimum system version" to "10.11.6" but also after restarting the OS I still obtain this message:

> "OS X 10.11.6 is installed on your computer, the application requires
>   OS X 10.12.1 or later

@Argus (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3611996/argus) and @laoyur (https://stackoverflow.com/users/6662165/laoyur) said that they were able to make Xcode work without updating macOS.

How can I make Xcode 9 work without upgrading macOS or anyway how can I submit iOS apps to the App Store with MacBook A1181 (until I get a new Mac)?

Comment: you have change minimum version in infoPlist of "Filemerge"  Application under xcode package ?

Comment: Yes, in all contents of all .app, .framework and .plugin until when grep returned empty result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having tried everything I found only the solution to force the upgrade of MacBook A1181 from MacOS X 10.11 (El Capitan) to MacOS X 10.12 (Sierra) with this tool (after shutting off SIP from Recovery Terminal with "csrutil disable"):

http://dosdude1.com/sierrapatch.html

and installing manually Xcode 9.2, downloaded from

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Deploying of debug releases cannot be done from current releases of iTunes 12, so I found this method inside Xcode:
Xcode => Window => Devices and Simulator

choosing the attached device and dragging the IPA into Installed Apps.

ps I had to apply also a patch for os system cache rebuilding and brightness control:

https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macos-10-12-sierra-unsupported-macs-thread.1977128/page-200#post-25104669

Thanks a lot to @dosdude1 for sharing all his knowledge about this problem.