# how to update Xcode to 9.3 and in mac sierra

Tags: xcode

*I have Xcode 9.2 installed on my sierra i want to update Xcode without update to heigh sierra?*  **I can't find Xcode update in App Store**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 9.3 will work on OS High Sierra because the Xcode version is dependent on MacOS version

You can also refer this link [How do I install Xcode 9 without updating macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224905/how-do-i-install-xcode-9-without-updating-macos)